# Can windows application be used as an answer in main?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368385/8698). I understand that, in theory, it can work in wine. But there is no claim about it whatsoever that it is 100% functional.

I've written my 2 cents as comment on the answer:

> That links a paid solution that downloads an exe application (a.k.a. Windows Application). How can it be used in Ubuntu? Looking at the layout of the website (Sorry to say, but it has spyware written all over it), personally, I'd think twice before installing that software

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it is acceptable, as long as the software is know to work using WINE and there is no other obvious solution.

***Not in that specific case though...***
That answer was just deleted by *je* because it sounded like spam, user will be monitored and suspended/removed if there are more posts like that.

Use common sense where possible, it will make our lives so much easier. Spam is spotted from miles away, normally.